# how can we remove style name mistake in v23values-v23.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

i have got error at all the R.layout used in the main activity (cannot resolve symbol'R').

from gradle sync i got some errors

at v23values-v23.xml

at v23values-v23.xml

Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Comment: change your Build Tool version to 23.0.1 in build.gradle

Comment: please so us you build.gralde (parts which are showable is enough)

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scenemakerz.screenshot"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}

Comment: where did you define your 23.0.0 dependencies and build tool version?